# Finding distinct sub document with where clause

Tags: mongodb

Given the following schema, I'm trying to find all distinct sub-document (item) for a condition.

```
{
   "basket": "one",
   "color":"brown",
   "items": [
        {
            "id":123,
            "name": "apple"
        },
        {
            "id":234,
            "name": "banana"
        },
    ]
}, 
{
   "basket": "2",
   "color":"brown",
   "items": [
        {
            "id":345,
            "name": "orange"
        },
        { 
            "id":123,
            "name": "apple"
        },
    ]
},
{
   "basket": "3",
   "color":"blue",
   "items": [
        {
            "id":345,
            "name": "orange"
        },
        { 
            "id":456,
            "name": "pineapple"
        },
    ]
}
```

Is there a way in mongodb to get all distinct items where the basket color is "brown"?

Ideally, result should be:

```
    {
        "id":123,
        "name": "apple"
    },
    {
        "id":234,
        "name": "banana"
    },
    { 
        "id":345,
        "name":"orange"
    }
```

Comment: `db.collection.distinct("items",{"color":"brown"})`

Comment: > `db.collection.distinct("item.name", {"color": "brown"})` .  Also note that in one case you have 'items' and in the others you have 'item'

Comment: Edited so all refers to "items". Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official doc here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct

`db.collection.distinct(field,query)`

where:

field - The field for which to return distinct values (string).

query - A query that specifies the documents from which to retrieve the distinct values (document).

So in your case:

`db.collection.distinct("items",{"color":"brown"})`

Answer (score 1):

After that you can run following-

In case of **"items"** sub-document

```
db.Collection_Name.distinct("items",{"color": "brown"})
```